# Using VirtualBox for Mobile App Development?

Tags: android, mobile, android-emulator, virtualbox

I keep wanting to use VitualBox for Mobile App Development, but I can't seem to get the emulator to run fast enough inside the already-emulated 32-bit machine.

Is there any way around this?

Now while it doesn't seem to me like there is an answer to this question, I figured I'd ask it anyway.

P.S. I have a 64-bit machine.

Comment: this is the moral to the story in the movie Inception.  If you run a VM inside a VM  inside a VM time is really slow :P

Comment: I don't understand the question... I do android on 64bit OS with out ANY issues. What are your other machine specs?? Ram, CPU, HDD(speed)

Comment: @drubin I'm talking about the development emulator, not to be confused with projects like live android (http://code.google.com/p/live-android/)  And I like to run my development environment inside of virtual box so I don't lose it between subsequent hdd crashes.

Comment: Anybody got any ideas on this?  Like maybe somehow running the emulator outside of VB and deploying the app from inside virtualbox to the non-VM emulator (I think I just paradoxed myself...) but you know know what I mean...the emulator doesn't run on VirtualBox but the development environment does.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick: 4 (or more) core CPU, plenty of ram (>4GB) and install the virtual operating system on a disk other than the one your main OS uses (e.g. firewire/esata external drive).
Another virtualization software might be faster too, but that I don't know.

Comment: You're saying that an external firewire drive will be faster than the drive your OS is on? -1

Comment: No..!! I said that using a disk, other than the one your main operating system is running on, will make things go faster. It's simple, if you have the virtual operating system on the same disk as the main operating system, the disk needle will have to relocate itself when you are writing either on the main system or the virtual system and that takes "alot" of time. If you use another disk it will be faster, either internal or external! (continue below)

Comment: But if you choose to use an external disk the best option will be Firewire or eSata connection because a USB connection will need to use your CPU to process data transfer and Firewire/eSata won't.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the x86 build of android in another virtual machine instead of the emulated arm of the current SDK one... (rumor is google is going to move in that direction anyway).  Last I tried this, it booted/ran much faster than the arm emulator running on a physical machine, but the mouse emulation was painfully slow, maybe they've fixed that now.

(You have to set up adb over tcp manually or with your own script so that eclipse or whatever knows about this target)